# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sdsd'

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a very basic program in python
when I'm trying to enter a string so that the interpreter shows "invalid" from else block 
its showing an error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sdsd'

Code:

```
x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if x== 0:
  print("the number is 0")
elif x<10:
  print("the number is less than 10: ", x)
elif x>10:
  print("the number is greater than 10: ",x)
else:
  print("invalid")
```

Comment: The first line will throw an exception on invalid input so it will never reach the `if` block. [Converting String to Int using try/except in Python](//stackoverflow.com/a/8075959)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I am new to python  and I don't now how to do it. Although my code got executed it shows the error only when I try to enter a string

Comment: You will need to learn about exception handling eventually. You can start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have added an exception at the bottom of the program that will give you an error that you can define, rather than a syntax error you were previously getting.

You didn't have a rule set for if the value is equal to 10 either so I have included that. I agree with the user in the comments though, it's worth reading a bit more about exceptions and error handling: [execeptions and error handling in python](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions)

`while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        if x == 0:
            print("the number is 0")
        elif x < 10:
             print("the number is less than 10: ", x)
        elif x > 10:
            print("the number is greater than 10: ",x)
        elif x == 10:
            print("the number is equal to 10: ",x)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("No string values allowed")`